# WSS 2.0 - How to pull information from a list and display it on data view webpart?

Tags: web-part, data-view-web-part, wss-2.0

I have a wss 2.0 environment and want to use dataview webpart to pull information from a list. I also want to do calculations based on a number of items I have on my list. Basically I want to do a summary report based on the information I have on a list.

Many thanks.
Sep

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Designer to pull information from the list directly or via web services.

There is a good walk through on Office.Microsoft for the webservice side of things:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-soap-service-as-a-data-source-HA010355752.aspx

One good aspect of using the web services is that it doesn't matter which installation of SharePoint you have.

Hope this helps
Stephen

***EDIT***

I just realised if you want to do a summery of the data on the list why not just create a view on the list with all the calculations you need then add that to the web part page?

Stephen